# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in VLC HTTP-interface?

Tags: ajax, vlc

I am working on a new centralized interface for my VLC media players around the house. So I have made a website (or in the progress of)...

So anyways, I can add links the the different functions in the VLC http interface, and it works and I get a page with XML data. BUT if I instead make the same request using AJAX, I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

So how would I add the http headers for Access-ControlAllow-Origin? I have seen how you add it to Apache and ASPX but I would like to add it to a simple HTML file as VLC interface is.

So any input in this matter would be nice :)

Comment: This doesn't look very helpful: http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch05.html I think you'll need to make a change in the source and recompile.

Comment: Looks like the relevant part might be in `src/network/httpd.c`; there are instructions for Git here: http://wiki.videolan.org/Git#Getting_VLC_or_x264_source_code_via_Git

Comment: Actually I thought it would be easier than that, to just add a header inside the html code, but I guess that was not the case...

Comment: I also found this link about the exact problem, and a ticket to fix it inside VLC... http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/5482

Comment: IMHO it's more of an *invitation* for anyone to fix it. As for "add a header inside the HTML code", that's just what it is, as the pages are generated dynamically.

Comment: Ah ok :) I did find someone that did a patch for a similar problem. http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2010-August/076438.html It wasnt taken very well though... So I dont think this patch ever was implemented...

Comment: Well, you could always patch the source with it yourself, compile and use it in your VLC instances. It's not necessary for such changes to propagate upstream.